# Checking if Joined Table is Empty [PHP & MYSQL]

Tags: php, mysql, html, css

How do I check if my statement is empty? The below code just show nothing if the Join contains nothing. How do i get it to display the first part of my IF statement ( Your To-Do List is Empty! )?

```
<?php 

  $statement = $db->query('SELECT * FROM todo_item as ti INNER JOIN todo_category as tc ON ti.todo_id = tc.todo_id');

  if (empty($db))
  {
    echo "<p style='background-color:green;'><strong>Your To-Do List is Empty!</strong></p>";
  }
  else
    foreach($statement as $row): 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using PDO?
[PDOStatement::rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Comment: I figured it out using $statement->rowCount() == 0

Comment: MySQL is a database engine and you could use in PHP to access the databse the mysql, mysqli and the PDO drivers also and if i remember correctly the mysqli_stmt can not be iterated. | @John Ayers: I'm glad. :-)

Answer (score 3):

you can do a mysql_num_rows and see how many rows are being returned. if that is 0, then you dont have anything in the db that matches the query

Comment: Ok that works but now throws this Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in index.php on line 50?

Comment: did you do mysql_num_rows($statement)? or just mysql_num_rows() ?

Comment: mysql_num_rows($statement) returns Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in index.php on line 50 as does mysql_num_rows($db)

Comment: i mean the format is mysql_num_rows($query) did you put your query's variable inside of the mysql_num_rows? if you are still getting confused [see this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

Answer (score 0):

try @mysql_num_rows($statement);

Another way to count rows is by using
$row = mysql_fetch_row($statement);
$records = $row[0];